# Apache Drill not using whole direct memory

Tags: apache-drill

I have set direct memory to 44GB

`export DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY=${DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY:-"44G"}`,

but when I see usage of memory in the Drill dashboard, it's using only 3 or 4GB max. Any idea why ?

I am using ver. 1.14

[image]

Also I see that correct memory is assigned to each drillbit when I run

```
select * from sys.memory
```

[image]

Cheers

Comment: Maybe it does not need more memory? The `_MAX_` in parameter name usually indicates that it's just limit, but tool may use less of it.

Comment: @Justinas, I've thought the same and this is the most logical what comes to my mind. But, the query is quite heavy, where I am joining multiple tables where some have more than 1TB. And the query runs for more than 1 hours, hard to believe that it doesn't need more memory.

I also set planner.memory.max_query_memory_per_node to 18GB, to make sure there is no other limitation.

Comment: Could you try to set up higher max direct memory? What is the memory usage then?
Also you can setup higher parallelism for execution, it requires more memory.

Comment: With DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY=31GB , HEAP=8GB,  I changed planner.width.max_per_node from 1 to 3 and direct memory jumped to 5GB. Also i set planner.memory.max_query_memory_per_node 28GB. Still it's strange it only jumped to 5GB, also the query is failing with error after changing width.max_per_node to 3: RESOURCE ERROR: External Sort encountered an error while spilling to disk, Unable to allocate buffer of size 262144 (rounded from 209712) due to memory limit (521249697). Current allocation: 705315328

Comment: Apparently Drill working that way, that even though the query is very "heavy", it will still take only some portion of the memory.It's not taking all available resources. Just to keep still some memory available for more queries which can be executed. When I run simultaneously 3 queries, then the memory got increased.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a configuration issue:

1. Is DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY env variable already set in your environment? You could use Linux /proc/<pid>/environ to access the Drillbit process environment variables
2. Make sure that all your Drillbits are configured properly; it is possible that the foreman process didn't get configured properly